# Updating MySQL configuration to avid error: "A partitioned table is not allowed in a shared tablespace"

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning

I have exported a database from a MySQL 8 database in the cloud and I am importing it to a database of the the same version on my local machine, but the import is failing with the error:

`ERROR 1478 (HY000) at line 52372: InnoDB : A partitioned table is not allowed in a shared tablespace.`

Before I load it, I drop drop database and remake the database. Then I run `database_name < sqldump.sql`

My local MySQL config looks like this:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
max_allowed_packet = 1000M
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Is there some way for me to either:

1. set my tablespace on my local mysql to not be shared and then reload this file?
2. create a non-shared or general tablespace and specifically load this sql dump to that tablespace?

I don't particularly need any of the data in my local installation of mysql so I could complete get rid of what is there if needed.

EDITS:

1. Adding create table statement on one of the tables:
   I have multiple tables that are partitioned, so I am not sure which one is causing the issue, but here is an example of one of the tables-- what I think is the largest table:

```
indicators_v2_studentindicator | CREATE TABLE `indicators_v2_studentindicator` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `count` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `custom_completed_time` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_completed_by_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `indicator_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_value` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `district_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`district_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_student_indicator` (`indicator_id`,`student_id`,`district_id`),
  KEY `indicators_v2_studen_custom_completed_by__0b8259f0_fk_sl_users_` (`custom_completed_by_id`),
  KEY `indicators_v2_studen_student_id_f5d95e9b_fk_sl_users_` (`student_id`),
  KEY `indicators_v2_studen_indicator_id_k9h7g1b7_fk_indc_v2_` (`indicator_id`),
  KEY `indicators__indicat_a34c4f_idx` (`indicator_id`,`student_id`,`district_id`,`value`),
  KEY `indicators_v2_studentindicator_district_id_31e295d6` (`district_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134160227 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST (`district_id`)
(PARTITION p_district_id_1 VALUES IN (1) TABLESPACE = `innodb_file_per_table` ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION p_district_id_3 VALUES IN (3) TABLESPACE = `innodb_file_per_table` ENGINE = InnoDB,
... [many more partition statements, omitted for brevity]
 PARTITION p_district_id_127 VALUES IN (127) TABLESPACE = `innodb_file_per_table` ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p_district_id_128 VALUES IN (128) TABLESPACE = `innodb_system` ENGINE = InnoDB,
```

Strangely, at a certain point, I see that the tablespace actually changes from `innodb_file_per_table` to `innodb_system` -- could that be an issue?

Comment: Can you include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>;` for your partitioned table? And also include the result of `SELECT VERSION();`. I tested on MySQL 8.0.26 and I was able to create a partitioned table with `innodb_file_per_table` disabled, and I did not get this error.

Comment: `PARTITIONing` is rarely useful; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @BillKarwin `8.0.19` is my version in my local machine I am loading the db into, `8.0.16` is the version where the database was dumped from.  I am adding this and the create table statement above.

Comment: @RickJames We partitioned the table because there are 90 million rows in it and most operations happen within one of the partitions. It sped up operations a lot.

Comment: Please show us the `SELECT` that benefitted from this `PARTITIONing`.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html#create-table-partitioning says:

> Placing InnoDB table partitions in shared InnoDB tablespaces is not supported. Shared tablespaces include the InnoDB system tablespace and general tablespaces.

So change this:

```
PARTITION p_district_id_128 VALUES IN (128) TABLESPACE = `innodb_system` ENGINE = InnoDB,
```

to this:

```
PARTITION p_district_id_128 VALUES IN (128) TABLESPACE = `innodb_file_per_table` ENGINE = InnoDB,
```

You can't use any value except `innodb_file_per_table`. The only purpose of this option as far as I know is to allow you to override the configuration option `innodb_file_per_table` if its global setting is OFF at the time you create your partitioned table.